# Retrieve all properties for a specific Automation in a child Business Unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, automationstudio

I would like to retrieve all properties of an Automation at Child Business Unit.

When I run this SOAP Call, with a Child Business Unit MID, I get all properties for active Automations but of the Parent Business Unit.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <fueloauth>Token</fueloauth>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <ClientIDs>
            <ID>BU MID here</ID>
         </ClientIDs>
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>automation</ObjectType>
            <Properties>*</Properties>
            <Filter xmlns:q1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="q1:SimpleFilterPart">
               <q1:Property>IsActive</q1:Property>
               <q1:SimpleOperator>equals</q1:SimpleOperator>
               <q1:Value>True</q1:Value>
            </Filter>
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fuel oauth tokens are MID specific.  When you retrieve your fuel Oauth to add to your soap request, be sure to include account_id, the MID of your child BU, in the Json payload of the request.  The account_id value will be your child BU's MID.

Some documentation found here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-app.htm

The last portion, Refresh Access Token, contains the JSON payload and properties required.